# Open liberty connecting Azure postgreSql database with azure workload identity

Tags: java, azure-aks, open-liberty, azure-identity

I have deployed my application on azure kubernetes service pod. My application is connected to azure postgreSql database using password authentication(azure AD). Now I want to replace password authentication with passwordless Azure workload identity authentication. I have successfully created service account and federation credential on managed identity. Now I am looking for some sample configuration in open liberty how to connect with azure workload identity.I tried but not able to do that. Please share any example

Comment: I've not tried this yet with Azure Database for PostgreSQL but it looks like once you have everything configured from an identity perspective, you should be able to have your app retrieve an access token then use that as the PGPASSWORD. Here is a doc on that. https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/postgresql/single-server/how-to-connect-with-managed-identity#creating-a-postgresql-user-for-your-managed-identity

Comment: Your Java application running on Open Liberty needs to programmatically obtain an Azure AD token using Managed Identity. 
After obtaining the token, the next step is to use it for connecting to your Azure PostgreSQL database. This will depend on whether your JDBC driver supports Azure AD token-based authentication and how it accepts these tokens.
In Open Liberty, you configure data sources in the server.xml file. Here, you'll need to adapt the configuration to include properties for Azure AD authentication.
Deploy your application on AKS with the Managed Identity setup correctly.